# R: nested loop, extending data frame with new observations

Tags: r, loops, nested

Unable to find a solution to my problem.

I have a dataset of .txt files, named after their time of observation, e.g.: 2018-07-04-04-53.txt. All these .txt-files are stored within one folder.

My aim is to create a new data.frame containing the information from within these .txt files.

First I gather the names of the files in the folder:

```
nam = list.files(path = "C:/Users/.../data")
```

then, I create a vector containing integers from 1: length of the variable

```
nrv = c(1:length(nam))
```

After this, I prepare my "dummy" data.frame, which I want to fill with the following nested loops. (I tried filling the data.frame with rbind, but it would always delete the preciously filled data)

```
nrnam = length(nam)


data = data.frame("year"=c(1:nrnam), "month"=c(1:nrnam), "day"=c(1:nrnam), "hour"=c(1:nrnam), "min"=c(1:nrnam))
```

The idea behind this is to create a df similar to a matrix, but with a header (my original input data is extremly compressed as it needs to be transported via iridium)

This is the for loop I tried using, to fill in the correct observation dates..

```
 for (i in nam) {

  for (ii in nrv) {

  # Einlesen des Datums aus dem Namen der Datei


  yr = substr(i,1,4)
  mo = substr(i,6,7)
  da = substr(i,9,10)
  hr = substr(i,12,13)
  mn = substr(i,15,16)

  data$year[ii] = yr
  data$month[ii] = mo
  data$day[ii] = da
  data$hour[ii] = hr
  data$min [ii] = mn


  } 
}
```

Just as an examply fo you guys: "i" conains 41 characters (2018-07-04-04-53.txt to 2018-07-12-10-51.txt), "ii" are 41 files in total, so nrnam should be integer 1:41.

My basic idea was:

```
1) go to file 1 (here 2018-07-04-04-53.txt) 
2) gather the observation date from file name
3) place it at row [ii] in my df. 
4) do it for all 41 files...
```

My problem: the loop fill in the correct date from the last .txt file for all 41 rows. So it´s all the same.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: I recommend the `purrr` package to make this process simpler and more reliable: https://serialmentor.com/blog/2016/6/13/reading-and-combining-many-tidy-data-files-in-R

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```r
setwd("U:/Playground/StackO/")

df <- data.frame(files = list.files())

library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

df$date <- ymd_hm(df$files)  
df$month <- month(df$date)

df
#>                  files                date month
#> 1 2018-07-04-04-53.txt 2018-07-04 04:53:00     7
#> 2 2018-07-06-11-51.txt 2018-07-06 11:51:00     7
#> 3 2018-07-12-10-51.txt 2018-07-12 10:51:00     7
```

`lubridate` is a package that is used to manipulate dates. It greatly simplifies the workflow as you dont have to create your own functions and think about edge cases.

You can still use your way like this:
    df$month2 <- substr(df$files, 6,7)

```r
df
#>                  files                date month month2
#> 1 2018-07-04-04-53.txt 2018-07-04 04:53:00     7     07
#> 2 2018-07-06-11-51.txt 2018-07-06 11:51:00     7     07
#> 3 2018-07-12-10-51.txt 2018-07-12 10:51:00     7     07
```